# Searching in only one subarray of 3d array in Processing

Tags: arrays, search, processing

I have a 3D array of int values and I want to search just through one of the subarrays for a specific value. While I could for-loop my way through every possible combination of the below code.

```
array[numberIwant][1-255[1-255];
```

That seems like overkill. I've come across the foreach type of for and thought that might be the answer to my quest but either it's not or I don't understand it well enough to get it to work. Could anyone suggest the way this should be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The foreach and the for loop will have almost identical processing time for an array of that size.
Although it might seem like overkill it is not, you will need to do a triple nested for loop then have an if statement seeing if the number you want was found.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I'm definitely running into issues with how processor intensive the process is. Might need to devise a better way of storing information.